# Wordpress Dashboard Characters Messed Up

Tags: encoding

I recently added a new post, and afterwards, many of the text lines on the wordpress dashboard appear messed up, almost as if they are protecting from a security breach or something.

[image]

I have tried disabling all plugins, emptying the cache, using a different browser, but none of these seem to work.

I am developing locally too, not sure if that has any bearing.

Many thanks for any help in advance

Comment: "WPZOOM News" is something custom. Please add a screenshot where you disabled everything and switched back to one of the  Twenty* themes.

Comment: This is an icon font. Use a clean setup, and check your local font directory for errors.

Answer (score -1):

Check the source code of the admin page, and search for `meta charset`. You page should contain a `<meta charset='utf-8' />` tag to instruct the browser the characters on your page are encoded in Unicode (UTF-8). This character encoding supports all characters, and is also recommended encoded for your pages for indexing in Google. If you page is not in UTF-8, Google converts it to UTF-8 before indexing it in their cache. So not having your page in UTF-8 can have unexpected and undesired results in Google's indexation.

Comment: `<meta charset='utf-8' />` is completely irrelevant and not used by any browser when there is already a proper HTTP header. And WordPress sends always a correct HTTP header.